# F9 key with BYOBU

Tags: terminal, iterm

I have installed BYOBU via Brew and all the F keys work except for the F9 key which happens to be the key used to get to the menu. I have worked around this by editing the ~/.byobu/status files manually. It would be nice to get this working. Has anyone fixed this? I don't think it's a $TERM issue.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm running into this same problem now

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: what's the output of `byobu-config`? Maybe `python-newt` is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Byobu guys have done some work porting it to OS X. I did a fresh install via Brew and it works like it does in linux. They eliminated the need to use the F9 key. That functionality can be achieved by running.

```
  $byobu-config
```